# Javascript. Swap two variables. How it works?

Tags: javascript, javascript-1.7

Saw in a single source next:

```
[param_o,param_got] = [param_got,param_o];
```

This code swap variables `param_o` & `param_got`.But how `[param_o,param_got] = [param_got,param_o]` works, if `[]` is new instance of  `Array` in Javascript ?

**EDIT**
Try checking:

```
var param_o = 1;
var param_got = 2;
[param_o,param_got] = [param_got,param_o];
console.log(param_o+" "+param_got);

// 2 1
```

Comment: This doesn't work: `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. You cannot assign a value to another value (an array in this case).

Comment: @Felix Kling check in console

Comment: I did, that's where I have the error from.

Comment: @FelixKling it works in FireFox but not Chrome.

Comment: @SomeKittens: Ah, then FF might already implement some ES6 feature (or apparently not a ES6 feature).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This notation is called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29) and is part of Javascript 1.7:

> Destructuring assignment makes it possible to extract data from arrays
>   or objects using a syntax that mirrors the construction of array and
>   object literals.
>
> The object and array literal expressions provide an easy way to create
>   ad-hoc packages of data. Once you've created these packages of data,
>   you can use them any way you want to. You can even return them from
>   functions.
>
> One particularly useful thing you can do with destructuring assignment
>   is to read an entire structure in a single statement.

The [first sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Avoiding_temporary_variables) actually demonstrates explicitly that this is useful to avoid temporary variables as in your code sample.

Firefox has supported this feature since Firefox 2 already. For Chrome the [bug is still open after 3 years](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=811). IE11 doesn't support it either from what I've just tested.